Is there a way for fixing the black screen in the flutter package video_player?
In the beginning everything is working, all videos are playing. But when I trigger a hot reload or delete a video, the streambuilder rebuilds itself (because it is listening to cloud firestore collection) and then the videos are not working anymore.
I found that the only way is to exit the application, clear the data and then head back to the application. Is there any fix or alternative way for this problem ?
